# bash: check if string starts with "/*"

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash-script I need to check if the string `$HEADER` starts with the character sequence "/*". I was trying:

```
if [ $(echo $HEADER | cut -c 1-2) = '/*' ]
```

It's not working as expected. It seems that the string is compared to the file list of the root directory.

How can I protect the characters / and * to be interpreted from the shell?

To protect the characters with a backslash isn't working either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the result of the command substitution is subject to file name generation. You need to quote *that*, as well as the expansion of `$HEADER` in the command substitution.

```
if [ "$(echo "$HEADER" | cut -c 1-2)" = '/*' ]
```

Since you are using `bash`, using the `[[` command (which can perform pattern matching) is a superior solution though, [as Jahid has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072736/1126841).

```
if [[ $HEADER = '/*'* ]]
```

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
if [[ $HEADER = '/*'* ]]
```

Another solution would be:

```
if [ "${HEADER:0:2}" = '/*' ]
```

Or

```
if [[ "${HEADER:0:2}" = '/*' ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
if [[ $(echo $HEADER | grep -E '^\/\*' | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a few solutions, but

```
[ "${HEADER#/\*}" != "${HEADER}" ]
```

works with [POSIX shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_002) without using external tools (not counting `[`) or bashisms.

Interestingly enough, this approach was missing from the marked duplicate.